# Image size increases after encryption

Tags: java, image-processing, netbeans, encryption, bufferedimage

I have developed a project to encrypt a image. The program works fine but after encrypting a 148 KB png image it becomes 257 KB. When the same file is decrypted back i am getting the old image back but the image is now 219 KB. Why does the size almost doubles?

My code: [Cannot read image in jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243928/cannot-read-image-in-jar?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Encrypt the imaage purely as binary data (the bytes). Reading an image and then writing an image in java might not yield the highest compression, and with lossy compression deteriorates in quality.

Answer (score 0):

It's properly not your encryption/decryption step that is the problem, but rather how you read and write the PNG.

You ought to read and write the PNG using binary streams like `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`. By keeping it binary you ensure you don't change the data.

The reason the images changes size (148 KB -> 219 KB) is that you don't preserve all properties from the original file.

As an example the output width, height and type are hardcoded with the following statement (instead of populating it from the original image):

```
BufferedImage writeImage = new BufferedImage(512, 512, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
```

Comment: But I have the same width and height of image as of original one. still the size is increases. why?

Comment: Could be another color depth giving more data, or addition of an alpha layer. The point is that the png is unnecessarily unpacked and repacked - and apparently a few properties have not been preserved. That being said, the input to encrypt should just be a binary stream. The encrypt should not care if the file being encrypted is a picture, a textfile or something else.

Comment: Actually I m encrypting an image with RC4 like algorithm i.e. doing ` XOR ` of image with key. i m doing nothing (explicitly) which will result in increase in size of encrypted image. I really want to track this down. please help me.

Comment: You are unpacking a compressed image (the PNG file) into memory, and then recreating a compressed version of the image. When you recreate the file. You don't have any code that preserve the properties from the original image, but instead hardcode size + color mode (TYPE_BYTE_GRAY). When you recreate the image you get default options that influence how the image is recreated, and those the size of the image. Compare the properties of the before and after image or something similar.